# In the Verified Software Toolchain, how can I specify some Clight which is not the body of a function, and which I'm generating from within Coq?

Tags: coq, formal-verification

I would like to write a Gallina function of a type like `gen_code : Foo -> statement` and then prove that it generates code that satisfies a particular specification. I do have an informal Hoare triple in mind; however, I'm not terribly familiar yet with VST, and I'm not sure exactly how to turn it something that the framework can work with. I think I want a theorem of the form `forall {Espec : OracleKind} (foo : Foo), semax ?Delta (P foo) (gen_code foo) (normal_ret_assert (Q foo))`, where I know what `P` and `Q` are, but I'm not sure what to put for `?Delta`. It's worth noting that I have some functions defined in C that I've verified already which I want to invoke from the code generated by `gen_code`, so presumably `?Delta` needs to involve the signatures of those somehow. I assume it probably also needs to mention the free variables of `gen_code foo`, and here I'm similarly lost.

Comment: Have you already gone through the material from this summer school: https://github.com/DeepSpec/dsss18/tree/master/vc

Comment: In what way the fact that it's generated in Coq makes things different?

Comment: @Li-yaoXia I have not! You're right, being generated in Coq is secondary; the main thing is that I want to give it a spec independently of being part of a function body—I'll edit the question to reflect that. Being generated *is* mildly significant, though, insofar as it means that I think I might need to be generating my `Delta` along with it? I'm not sure, that's why I'm asking.